# Storing Firebase downloadUrl in Mongoose DB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, firebase, mongoose-schema

This is client side code that to send file and newPost using 2 different path

```
const hanldeSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newPost = {
            username: user.username,
            userId: user._id,
            title,
            desc,
        };
        if(file){
            const data = new FormData();
            const chance = new Chance();
            const randomString = chance.string({ length: 20});
            const filename = Date.now() + randomString;
            data.append("name", filename);
            data.append("file", file);
            newPost.photo = filename;
            try {
                await axios.post("/upload", data);
            }   catch(err){
                console.error(err)
            }
        }
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('/posts', newPost);
            window.location.replace("/post/" + res.data._id);
        }
        catch(err){

        }
    }
```

This is where file uploading to firebase and generating url /index.js file/

```
app.post('/server/upload', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const downloadUrl = await uploadFileToFirebase(req.file);
        res.status(200).json({ downloadUrl });
    } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to upload file" });
    }
});

const uploadFileToFirebase = async (file) => {
    const { filename } = file;
    const metadata = {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg'
    };
    const storageRef = ref(storage2, `/files/${filename}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, readFileSync(file.path), metadata);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        uploadTask.on('state_changed',
        (snapshot) => {
            // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
            const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
            switch (snapshot.state) {
                case 'paused':
                    console.log('Upload is paused');
                    break;
                case 'running':
                    console.log('Upload is running');
                    break;
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            switch (error.code) {
                case 'storage/unauthorized':
                    // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                    break;
                case 'storage/canceled':
                    // User canceled the upload
                    break;
                case 'storage/unknown':
                    // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
                    break;
            }
        },
        async () => {
            // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
            
            const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
            console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
            resolve(downloadURL);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

This is where saving data to database /post.js file/

```
  
    router.post("/", async(req, res) => {
    const newPost = new Post(req.body);
    try{
        const savedPost = await newPost.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedPost);
        console.log("goodjob")
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
    })
```

Everything is working fine, but I can't save generated downloadURL to mongoose with other datas like title and desc. How to achieve this?

Comment: did your image get saved in firebase ?

Comment: @Naveen Ravi Yes